# Problems setting XAML Button Style

Tags: wpf, xaml, button

The effect I am going for: I have a set of buttons that really should be a collection of radio buttons (one and only one active at a time).  I want to make the last pressed button a different color (background), switching when another button is pressed.  I have this working in the code behind ***EXCEPT*** the background doesn't change until the mouse is moved outside the area the button is in.

I would greatly prefer to completely set button styles from the XAML code behind. I found a similar article that had a snippet I tried.  It fixes that problem, but it has so many other issues (text disappears, button size issues, border size issues, alignment issues) that I'm not going to be able to use it as is.  I've tried eliminating pieces, adding pieces, but I'm making it worse.

```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
      <!-- Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" / -->
      <!-- Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,4,12,4" />
      <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" /-->
      <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
               <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                       BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                       BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}" />
                </Border>
             </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
       <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="Maroon"/>
             <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
           </Trigger>
           <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
              <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
           </Trigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
```

This is in the main view of a plugin I created, which is part of a larger application.  It has some affects on this view, and then different effects on a dynamic region within this view. It's complicated.  As I said, I'd much rather do it in C# and have it do what I tell it to do.

It seems there should be a tiny piece of the above that would do the trick, but I've read some articles about Button "not respecting" this or that.  Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you referring to the `Blueish` color it does when you MouseOver?

Comment: I think you are going about this the wrong way. Use RadioButton controls and use RadioButton styles. Do you have Expression Blend?

Comment: I agree w/ Rhyous with the exception on using Blend.

Comment: I'd consider moving to radio buttons if I wasn't at end of project.  As is, it is working, so it is staying as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the < Setter Property="Template" / > section and it is much less wonky.  It's slightly different than the original, but in an ok/good way.  I still have this in the main view of my plugin:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="Maroon"/>
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
       </Trigger>
       <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
       </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

In regards of your scenario, I would consider using a radio button (re: TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}" ) because this will allow you to take advantage of the IsChecked property, and you will be able to define style changes against IsChecked without any code behind.

For the radio Button, in the template you would simply add (or edit)

```
<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
</Trigger>
```

For example, if you would like the background of your button to become white when it is checked (or any components of the template, if you target it with TargetName="MyElementName").